# How to select data using data from another database?

Tags: mysql, select

I'd like to do a `SELECT` query. The parameter is taken from another database. So, I am using data from `scg_surat.t_pembayaran` for selecting data from `scg_vendor.vendor`

```
SELECT * FROM scg_vendor.vendor WHERE id_vendor IN (SELECT scg_surat.t_pembayaran.REKANAN FROM `scg_surat.t_pembayaran` GROUP BY scg_surat.t_pembayaran.REKANAN)
```

The query gives this error `Table 'scg_vendor.scg_surat.t_pembayaran' doesn't exist`.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with your backtick operators on the database, table, and column name. MySQL is reading it as a column selection from your current database selection.

The backtick operators need to be separated

```
`scg_surat`.`t_pembayaran`.`REKANAN`
```

Your query should look like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `scg_vendor`.`vendor` 
WHERE `id_vendor` IN (
    SELECT `scg_surat`.`t_pembayaran`.`REKANAN` 
    FROM `scg_surat`.`t_pembayaran` 
    GROUP BY `scg_surat.`t_pembayaran`.`REKANAN`
)
```

I also suggest using aliases instead of the full table names.

```
SELECT v.*
FROM `scg_vendor`.`vendor` AS v
WHERE v.`id_vendor` IN(
    SELECT p.`REKANAN` 
    FROM `scg_surat`.`t_pembayaran` AS p 
    GROUP BY REKANAN
)
```

Answer (score 1):

To Select Tables from different database you must specify your database before the table. for example.

```
Select * From `DataBase1`.`MyTable1`;
```

I am a little confused of which is your database name, but i am guessing what you are looking for is this?

```
SELECT `scg_surat.t_pembayaran`.`REKANAN` 
FROM `scg_surat.t_pembayaran` 
GROUP BY `scg_surat.t_pembayaran`.`REKANAN`
```

Where `scg_surat.t_pembayaran` is the name of your database and `REKANAN` is the name of your table?

Editted:

Try This query then:

```
SELECT * FROM `scg_vendor`.`vendor`
WHERE `id_vendor` IN
(SELECT `REKANAN` FROM `scg_surat`.`t_pembayaran` GROUP BY `REKANAN`);
```

Comment: My databases are `scg_surat` and `scg_vendor`.

Comment: My query using `WHERE ... IN (...)`

Comment: I have edited my answer, give it a try and let me know if it works or not.

Answer (score 0):

You just wrong in Your `select statement` when you already do specify table just call the column not the database and table.

Try :

```
SELECT * FROM scg_vendor.vendor WHERE id_vendor IN 
(SELECT REKANAN FROM scg_surat.t_pembayaran
GROUP BY REKANAN)
```

Avoid using `*` that's not good base practice

Comment: Somebody tell me why i got downvoted? Is it my answer wrong? Not provide any detail or something? So in the future i could give more useful answer.. :)

Comment: The advice you gave for the select column name was already using valid syntax and your `FROM` statement is invalid syntax. Effectively resulting in the same error message the OP has an issue with.

Comment: Oh the backtick in from statement? My bad.. Thanks for your advice.. :)